# MSP430G2231 Serial out using Energia

Tags: serial, msp430, energia

I am trying to read an analog signal using the Analog.Read() function and output 1 or 0 depending on the value of the analog signal. While testing using a serial monitor, I always get the symbol for 'phi'instead of 0 and the 'square box with question mark'instead of 1. Please help.

```
    const int analogInPin = A3;
    int inputValue=0;
    int ch1=1,ch2=0;
    void setup()
   {

     pinMode(A0, INPUT);
     Serial.begin(9600);
    }

    void loop()
    {
      inputValue = analogRead(analogInPin);
      if(inputValue>240)
      Serial.print('1');
      else 
      Serial.print('0');
      delay(10);   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I remember well you can use either:

Serial.print(1);

or

Serial.write('1');

To display 1 in the serial monitor.

Comment: I tried that too,but the same outcome with a different character.

Comment: You might try also Serial.print("1");

Comment: That doesn't work either.

Comment: You may have a problem somewhere else because I'm pretty sure that this code works. You could look to the TX line on the oscilloscope, to see what does generate the microcontroller.

Comment: This is not related to the problem you're describing but in your code you're setting A0 as an input but reading from A3.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to output 1 or 0 simply remove your single quotes and use the following:

```
Serial.print(1);

Or 

Serial.print(0);
```

Your code is printing out the ASCII value of 1 and 0...